# Migrate excel data to postgres database

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I'm trying to migrate data from an excel file to postgres but this problem is blocking it.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi - please provide information about the error. At the moment you have provided nothing that anyone could use to help you

Comment: Dates from the XLS are defined as String, convert them to a Date